Add magic link to Staging Ground
I want to propose a little "make the life easier" feature.
I reviewed a lot of questions and noticed that many questions were not initially posted on the Staging Ground.
I do not want to discuss the need to use the Staging Ground first!
The thing is that most questions from new users do not meet the guidelines. As such, they normally get slandered and overthrown with downvotes. 
I normally link the users [tour] and [ask], as well as [repro] as a guideline comment.
The proposal:
Can we get a link such as [staging] so that I (and others) don't need to always use [Staging Ground](https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground) as a link?

It doesn't seem like a user gets to control whether his/her own post goes through SG or not, so I am not sure whether a magic link like [staging] would help.

It would help to guide the user directly to the staging ground so that he can specifically ask his question there first. I'm not sure if new users are actually aware of the staging ground and that they would receive more (and more friendly) guidance to their questions.

I could be mistaken, but what I mean is that even when given that link, the user cannot choose to post on SG even if he wants. It's entirely up to the system. Do you have a concrete example that the user benefits from a comment like that?

I don't really see the benefit here; when would you need to post a comment to explicitly tell another user to visit the Staging Ground? If you just want a link for your own navigation, it's on the left hand side of the site or in the burger menu

@WeijunZhou you might be right. Maybe as an alternative a page that explains the Stagign Ground and how to use it such as a help page?

"how to use it" The users that need to know how to use the Staging Ground aren't the ones posting the questions, @tacoshy , it's the users who are reviewing the questions sent to the SG, and there is a page for that in the help centre.

Although you can access that link, sharing it with users with reputation below 500 wouldn't be useful as they can't access that link. Also as already mentioned by others the user can't control whether their question goes to the staging ground or not.

We don't slander new users in my experience.

I don't see any benefit to creating a magic link for [Staging]/[sg], or similar. For those that have access to the Staging Ground (SG) there is a link on the menu bar or in the burger menu on the left side and if a user doesn't have access, it's not displayed; trying to access the SG when not having permission results in a "Page not found" error.
Questions that go to the SG are displayed quite prominently when viewing both the home page, using the search tool, or when using things like custom filters (example), so even if users aren't aware the link is on the left, they'll see links to questions in the SG when browsing the site normally.
Having the ability to post comments that link to the Staging Ground quickly doesn't really therefore appear to provide much benefit, and it's likely to result in an error for many users. Based on a query in SEDE, over 98% of users would receive an error:



Total Users
Cannot Access SG
Can Access SG
Percentage Cannot Access SG




25,276,340
24,804,981
471,359
98.1351%



It also appears, perhaps, that you are under the impression that a user chooses whether or not to post in the SG; this is incorrect. An unknown percentage of eligible users are sent to the SG. As a result a non-small amount of eligible users still have their questions bypass the SG. Ideally, this should have been set to 100% by now, but it hasn't. I assume that once it does, your want for this feature will likely be voided.

I believe the rate at which new users' questions are sent to SG is controlled based on the rate at which questions currently in SG are reviewed, though I'm not sure of the details.

What's the point for this use-case? As far as I know, nobody can control whether their questions end up in SG or not. Even if you point someone / a question post that could use the SG treatment to SG, then what? There's no "migrate to SG" feature either. Just close the question if it should be closed.
Also, for what it's worth, there's a [help/sg] magic link.
